AWS CDK stopped working with AWS SSO leading to: Need to perform AWS calls for account [Account ID], but no credentials have been configured
CDK stopped working, it used to work fine, my coworker is able to locally deploy easily, we matched our configs, not working for me, resulting in:
Need to perform AWS calls for account [Account ID], but no credentials have been configured.
when calling cdk deploy --profile Test [edited]/Test/DynamoDbStack or any other combination of stack and env.
My .aws/config:
[default]
sso_start_url = https://[edited].awsapps.com/start
sso_region = us-east-1
sso_account_id = ...
sso_role_name = AdministratorAccess
region = us-east-1
output = json

[profile Test]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::[edited]:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole
source_profile = default

aws sso login works fine and I am able to get identity, sso is working, but cdk seems to look in the wrong place for credentials. My .aws/credentials file is empty, tried deleting it, tried empty values, tried fake values.
Tried:
rm -rf ~/.cdk
cd your/cdk/project
rm -rf cdk.out
export AWS_PROFILE=Test

Tried updating all the libs, aws, cdk, node, npm...
Spent about a week trying everything I could find in Github issues, here and reddit.
Appreciate you reading the whole thing.

Ok it seems like all I had to do after fixing everything I had in mind, is to restart my laptop.
(Yes I am ashamed)

just our of curiosity, you tried restarting bash/sh/zsh and it didn't work?

yes, tried that many times, not sure what happened but I should have tried this sooner.
